# Focus on listview rows

Tags: android, listview

So, I've got a custom listview

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ListView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/listview"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:choiceMode="singleChoice"
android:descendantFocusability="afterDescendants"
android:background="@color/gray"
android:dividerHeight="1dp"
android:focusable="false"
android:divider="@color/white" >
</ListView>
```

And rows :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:focusable="true"
android:id="@+id/layout"
android:orientation="horizontal" >

<FrameLayout
    android:id="@+id/left_frame"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="center_vertical" >

    <com.test.CustomImageView
        android:id="@+id/armnc_left_image"
        android:layout_width="35dp"
        android:layout_height="35dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="15dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
        android:contentDescription="@null"
        android:focusable="false"
        android:scaleType="fitCenter" />
</FrameLayout>

<com.test.CustomLabel
    android:id="@+id/title_label"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
    android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="15dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
    android:focusable="false"
    android:textSize="18sp" />

</LinearLayout>
```

I want my Layout be focusable and return an event.
But I search hours and can't find the solution...

Comment: What kind of events? Can you be more specific?

Comment: for event you mean you want to know on which row did you clicked?

Comment: Sorry, When the focus change, get an Focus event.

Comment: Focus on rows are randoms...